# Reading multiple files using FileRead() and adding them on React State

Tags: reactjs

So I'm building an app that allows you to chose more than one photo, on chose I set the files in `React State` then i listed for change for that state with `useEffect` so I can iterate and convert to base64 using FileRead to preview what I've uploaded. But I'm having a problem that the data I'm getting is weird, some of the files are read and added to the React State and some just appear just as `File`, here is the screenshot:

[Here is the screenshot of the Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlZtq.png) (can't add the object because is to long)

And here is how I add to the state the files on upload:

```js
<input
 className={styles.hidden_input}
 type='file'
 multiple='multiple'
 accept='image/*'
 onChange={(event) => {
 const files = event.target.files;
 if (files) setImages(files);
 else setImages(null);
}}
```

And here is how I convert them when uploads are made:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (images.length !== 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        let file = images[i];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          const single = reader.result;
          setImagesStream([...images, single]);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No images where found.');
    }
  }, [images]);
```

When I try to iterate, just the last image shows the other show blank, because aren't converted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to the setState of 'setImagesStream' so it can read from the current value in the updater instead of reading the current value rendered. Here is the [docs reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

Something like this should work:

```
setImagesStream((state) => {
     return [...state, single]
 });
```